# How to run and debug C++ application in Eclipse that's started with a script?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to use Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu for C++ development. I'm working on a large C++ project that leverages Tcl as a scripting language to kick off and control the application.

How can I configure Eclipse to launch the application using shell scripts rather than using a C++ "main" application? The shell scripts launch a Tcl application that in turn calls into the C++ application.

Also, is it possible to debug a C++ application using Eclipse and gdb that's started via a script? If so, how does one go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Without being able to provide you a straight solution, but Eclipse (gdb) can be attached to a running program - that may not help in your case.

What about trying to employ some kind of remote debugging? I.e. you start your program with gdb and configure gdb to wait for a remote debugger to attach? The 'remote' debugger will be on your local system, of course.

EDIT:
Start your program via

```
gdbserver localhost:1234 <executable>
```

Configure your debug session in Eclipse: 
- GDB Hardware Debugging 
- I had to select the "Standard GDB Hardware debugging launcher" (Debugger tab at the bottom for Helios)
- Check use remote target: Generic TCP/IP: localhost, port 1234

I didn't manage to resolve symbols yet, that might be a path issue.

Comment: Thanks for providing your input - I'll test this out ASAP and mark as the solution if it works.